# Can't access Openstack VM instances using floating IP

Tags: networking, virtualization, juju, openstack, ping

I performed a single node installation on an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server using conjure-up (https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/try-openstack) . The installation completed successfully.I am able to access the horizon dashboard after doing the port forwarding.

The openstack version installed is 2.3.1-Mitaka

I used lxd container to deploy the openstack on (lxd-init). 
The bridge name is lxdbr0.

```
lxdbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr fe:29:3f:95:33:74
          inet addr:10.150.23.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5979473 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7665921 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:1902164036 (1.9 GB)  TX bytes:87174216616 (87.1 GB)
```

The primary physical interface on the server on which the installation is done is eno1

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr bc:30:5b:ee:57:bc
          inet addr:10.x.x.39  Bcast:10.221.31.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:71774809 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:27467361 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:82425733947 (82.4 GB)  TX bytes:13855543051 (13.8 GB)
          Memory:dcb00000-dcbfffff
```

I've configured the networking following instructions given on this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yqFpyubsYfE and here

https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/install-guide-ubuntu/launch-instance-provider.html

https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/install-guide-ubuntu/launch-instance-selfservice.html

I launched a sample instance using the dashboard,but I am not able to ping/ssh to it from the server(outside world) or vice-versa.

The instance has both private Ips and Floating Ips allocated. The external network is a FLAT network with the physical network name as defined in the ml2 conf ini file in the **neutron-api/0** node.

I am new to Openstack and Networking, so mostly we are missing some steps to establish this connection of the vm instance to the outside world.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me out on this, been stuck up with this and it gets frustrating. All I want is to be able to get this instance to be accessed from outside.

The different openstack units/services such as neutron,nova,glance,etc have their IPs allocated like **10.150.23.x** and are all active.

```
lg@si-rd10-39:~$ sudo juju status
Model                         Controller                Cloud/Region         Version
conjure-openstack-novalx-937  conjure-up-localhost-88c  localhost/localhost  2.2.6

App                    Version       Status   Scale  Charm                  Store       Rev  OS      Notes
ceph-mon               12.2.0        active       3  ceph-mon               jujucharms   13  ubuntu
ceph-osd               12.2.0        active       3  ceph-osd               jujucharms  249  ubuntu
ceph-radosgw           12.2.0        active       1  ceph-radosgw           jujucharms  252  ubuntu
glance                 15.0.0        active       1  glance                 jujucharms  259  ubuntu
keystone               12.0.0        active       1  keystone               jujucharms  271  ubuntu
lxd                    2.0.10        active       1  lxd                    jujucharms   13  ubuntu
mysql                  5.6.34-26.19  active       1  percona-cluster        jujucharms  255  ubuntu
neutron-api            11.0.1        active       1  neutron-api            jujucharms  253  ubuntu
neutron-gateway        11.0.1        active       1  neutron-gateway        jujucharms  241  ubuntu
neutron-openvswitch    11.0.1        active       1  neutron-openvswitch    jujucharms  244  ubuntu
nova-cloud-controller  16.0.1        active       1  nova-cloud-controller  jujucharms  301  ubuntu
nova-compute           16.0.1        active       1  nova-compute           jujucharms  274  ubuntu
ntp                                  waiting      0  ntp                    jujucharms   18  ubuntu
openstack-dashboard    12.0.0        active       1  openstack-dashboard    jujucharms  251  ubuntu  exposed
rabbitmq-server        3.5.7         active       1  rabbitmq-server        jujucharms   68  ubuntu

Unit                      Workload  Agent  Machine  Public address  Ports              Message
ceph-mon/0*               active    idle   1        10.150.23.194                      Unit is ready and clustered
ceph-mon/1                active    idle   10       10.150.23.173                      Unit is ready and clustered
ceph-mon/2                active    idle   11       10.150.23.108                      Unit is ready and clustered
ceph-osd/0                active    idle   14       10.150.23.7                        Unit is ready (1 OSD)
ceph-osd/1                active    idle   15       10.150.23.70                       Unit is ready (1 OSD)
ceph-osd/2*               active    idle   2        10.150.23.213                      Unit is ready (1 OSD)
ceph-radosgw/0*           active    idle   13       10.150.23.34    80/tcp             Unit is ready
glance/0*                 active    idle   3        10.150.23.63    9292/tcp           Unit is ready
keystone/0*               active    idle   7        10.150.23.209   5000/tcp           Unit is ready
mysql/0*                  active    idle   0        10.150.23.32    3306/tcp           Unit is ready
neutron-api/0*            active    idle   8        10.150.23.25    9696/tcp           Unit is ready
neutron-gateway/0*        active    idle   4        10.150.23.155                      Unit is ready
nova-cloud-controller/0*  active    idle   9        10.150.23.221   8774/tcp,8778/tcp  Unit is ready
nova-compute/0*           active    idle   6        10.150.23.5                        Unit is ready
  lxd/0*                  active    idle            10.150.23.5                        Unit is ready
  neutron-openvswitch/0*  active    idle            10.150.23.5                        Unit is ready
openstack-dashboard/0*    active    idle   5        10.150.23.144   80/tcp,443/tcp     Unit is ready
rabbitmq-server/0*        active    idle   12       10.150.23.186   5672/tcp           Unit is ready

Machine  State    DNS            Inst id         Series  AZ
0        started  10.150.23.32   juju-76629f-0   xenial
1        started  10.150.23.194  juju-76629f-1   xenial
2        started  10.150.23.213  juju-76629f-2   xenial
3        started  10.150.23.63   juju-76629f-3   xenial
4        started  10.150.23.155  juju-76629f-4   xenial
5        started  10.150.23.144  juju-76629f-5   xenial
6        started  10.150.23.5    juju-76629f-6   xenial
7        started  10.150.23.209  juju-76629f-7   xenial
8        started  10.150.23.25   juju-76629f-8   xenial
9        started  10.150.23.221  juju-76629f-9   xenial
10       started  10.150.23.173  juju-76629f-10  xenial
11       started  10.150.23.108  juju-76629f-11  xenial
12       started  10.150.23.186  juju-76629f-12  xenial
13       started  10.150.23.34   juju-76629f-13  xenial
14       started  10.150.23.7    juju-76629f-14  xenial
15       started  10.150.23.70   juju-76629f-15  xenial
```

The instance private IP is 192.168.100.10

external/floating IP is 10.x.x.71

external gateway IP is 10.x.x.1

Router Ip is 10.x.x.73

The instance also has the security group rules set as below

```
ALLOW IPv4 icmp from 0.0.0.0/0
ALLOW IPv4 icmp to 0.0.0.0/0
ALLOW IPv4 1-65535/tcp to 0.0.0.0/0
ALLOW IPv4 1-65535/tcp from 0.0.0.0/0
```

**in the neutron-gateway/0 node**

vi /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/openvswitch_agent.ini

```
# mitaka
###############################################################################
# [ WARNING ]
# Configuration file maintained by Juju. Local changes may be overwritten.
###############################################################################
[ovs]
enable_tunneling = True
local_ip = 10.150.23.155
bridge_mappings = physnet1:br-ex

[agent]
tunnel_types = gre,vxlan
l2_population = True
enable_distributed_routing = False


[securitygroup]
firewall_driver = neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.OVSHybridIptablesFirewallDriver
```

**in the neutron-api/0 node**

vi /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini

```
# mitaka
###############################################################################
# [ WARNING ]
# Configuration file maintained by Juju. Local changes may be overwritten.
###############################################################################
[ml2]
type_drivers = gre,vxlan,vlan,flat,local
tenant_network_types = gre,vxlan,vlan,flat,local
mechanism_drivers = openvswitch,hyperv,l2population

path_mtu = 1500
[ml2_type_gre]
tunnel_id_ranges = 1:1000

[ml2_type_vxlan]
vni_ranges = 1001:2000

[ml2_type_vlan]
network_vlan_ranges = physnet1:1000:2000

[ml2_type_flat]
flat_networks = physnet1

[ovs]
enable_tunneling = True
local_ip = 10.150.23.25

[agent]
tunnel_types = gre,vxlan
[securitygroup]
enable_security_group = True
firewall_driver = neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.OVSHybridIptablesFirewallDriver
```

If there is any command you wish for me to run, please indicate on which node like neutron-api/0 or neutron-gateway/0, nova-compute/0 etc...

Also, ive seen when I try to modify certain files like the ml2 conf file, there is a warning

```
# mitaka
###############################################################################
# [ WARNING ]
# Configuration file maintained by Juju. Local changes may be overwritten.
###############################################################################
```

So, is there a way to make changes persist to such files?

Thanks in advance for your time !